# Avoid repetitive constructor for user-defined inherited classes

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, interface, constructor

```
// Library code
struct Entity;
struct Attachment { 
    Entity& entity;
    Attachment(Entity& mEntity) : entity(mEntity) { }
};

// ---
// User code
struct MyAttachment1 : Attachment { 
    // This is annoying to write for every attachment type
    // Especially when there are other constructor arguments
    // And if there are a lot of attachment types
    MyAttachment1(Entity& mEntity) : Attachment{mEntity} { }
};
struct MyAttachment2 : Attachment { 
    MyAttachment2(Entity& mEntity) : Attachment{mEntity} { }
};
// ...
```

As you can see from the code example, every type that derives from `Attachment` needs to define a *repetitive* constructor where an `Entity&` is passed to the base class constructor.

This would not be an issue, but in my projects I deal with 40-50+ attachments, and they also have their own parameters in their constructors.

It seems unnecessary having to explicitly pass `Entity&` as the first parameter.

One workaround I've found is using a `virtual void Attachment::init()` method that the user overrides, and that is called by the `Entity` after an `Attachment` has been added to it. This, however, uses an unnecessary `virtual` call and still requires the user to deal with boilerplate code.

**Is there a more elegant way to deal with this problem?**

Comment: Variadic constructors? `template<class... Args> MyAttachment1(int some_argument, Args&&... args) : Attachment{forward<Args>(args)...}, direct_member{some_argument} {}` (I guess another design would be better, but that would require more information..)

Comment: *"Is there a more elegant way to deal with this problem?"* -- No. There is not.  I can't even fathom how typing `Attachment{mEntity}` when you are writing a class constructor can possibly be considered a chore.  I mean, you're writing a whole class anyway.  If it's such a bother, create a macro in your text editor.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: alright. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: As an aside, you're copying the Entity, so why is the parameter not const?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is not a more elegant way to write it. I can't even fathom how typing `Attachment{mEntity}` when you are writing a class constructor can possibly be considered a chore. I mean, you're writing a whole class anyway. If it's such a bother, create a macro in your text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but in C++11 you can also do

```
struct MyAttachment1 : Attachment { 
    // Note, this imports ALL of the base constructors, you can't 
    // pick and choose
    using Attachment::Attachment;

};
```

See https://ideone.com/fceV4k

Comment: It doesn't help when user-defined inherited types have other parameters than `Entity&` in the constructor